# More compact/readable way of doing $($(this).children()[1]).html()) with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I often find myself doing things like this when manipulating tables:-

```
$($('table tr').children()[2]).html();
```

For when I want the cell in the 3rd column as a jQuery wrapped set. Selecting the node using `[n]` and then passing to `$()` to get a jQuery wrapped set.

Is there a neater more readable way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

```
$('table tr').children().eq(2).html();
```

---

you could alternatively use the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('table tr > :eq(2)').html();
```

Comment: Fantastic, I knew there would be a way! Thank you very much!